# Deleted media is showing in whatsapp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, redmi

My phone is **Redmi 8A Dual** with MUMI version 12 stable, Android 10 . In using WhatsApp, it is showing space of deleted images and videos. On clicking them *This file is not supported* is showing.

Does anyone know what to to?
I Don't understand what to do to remove these items.

[image: Screenshot of thumbnails that fail to render]